# How to make simple script that opens box with bio and image?

Tags: jquery

I want to make script that opens box with big image and short bio, when user click on small photo. Perfect example is [this page](http://www.deltaholding.rs/company_overview/board.84.html) .What is the easiest way to achieve this simple effect? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you inspect the source code of the page you're referring to? The function is right there...

Comment: I won't suggest ripping people's code off their website.
However, no harm just looking at how they implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve the effect with jquery UI's dialog+modal

Refer [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal).